# Parse - How to stop modal alert while app opening(foreground), when received remote notification IOS?

Tags: ios, notifications, parse-platform, push

I have a problem during I developing application IOS and I used Parse Push Notification Framework for push remote notification. the problem is when the application is running and the same time the notification has been sent, the application is display modal alert box automatically. So, I don't want the modal alert display. I spent much times on it, and I do research on internet, read documents but no result found, I feel nobody knew about this. Please Help me!

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg_new"];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];



    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];

    // ****************************************************************************

    // Uncomment and fill in with your Parse credentials:

    // [Parse setApplicationId:@"your_application_id" clientKey:@"your_client_key"];

    // ****************************************************************************

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"my_app_id" clientKey:@"my_client_key"];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];





    return YES;

}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

{

    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.

    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application

{

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 

    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application

{

    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

}



- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

{

    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application

{

    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

}



- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];

    currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];

    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if (error.code == 3010) {

        NSLog(@"Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.");

    } else {

        // show some alert or otherwise handle the failure to register.      NSLog(@"application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error);

    }

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {    
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

}
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make sure you DO NOT see notifications when the app is opening, set a BOOL isOpening to TRUE in your `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and set it to FALSE during `application:didFinishingLaunchingWithOptions:`, then change the behavior of didReceiveRemoteNotification: and the call to `PFPush handlePush:` accordingly.

You can try this instead:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isLaunching;

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    isLaunching = TRUE;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    isLaunching = FALSE;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    if (!isLaunching) {
        //Only fire the push handler if the application isn't active
        [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what that I want is to disable, stop alert dialog when the application opening foreground.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? I don't fully understand. You want to prevent an alert from being shown when the application is opening, and it isn't already open?

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Kreager for your reply. Yes, I wanted to prevent an alert from begin shown when the application is opening. Your code above(your answer) is just check if the application active or not, I already knew about this how to check it. but my problem is when I handlePush  [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; application active, and I send the notification the modal alert is shown. And I want to disappear the modal alert. I wanted to do the custom notification is application running.

Comment: If you don't understand what I said you can download the sample project from https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications to test to send notification when application is opening it will be show a modal alert.

Comment: I edited my original example to handle your needs as I understand them. Hope it helps!